# Disabling back, forward, seek for videos to be run on flash player

Tags: javascript, flash

I want to take much control of the flash player playing my videos for the users on my website like I want to restrict them seeking to a position in the video, to initialize the video from the place the user left of at the first time they logged in and they wont be able to see again what they have already seen so far etc. Could you please help me how can I achieve this? I have never done ActionScript programming before but I know Javascript pretty well. Would that be possible with JS or so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The player would have to been deliberately designed to be configurable/scritable via JavaScript. If it is not, you are out of luck.